# Monitoring and autorestarting Jetty if it runs out of memory

Tags: monitoring, jetty

How can I monitor health of Jetty instance and automatically restart instance, if it runs out of memory?

Answer (score 2):

I would look at something like [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to watch the process and set a memory threshold for restarting the process.

Using [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), you can have a statement like:

```
check process jetty
    with pidfile "/var/run/blah...
    start program = "/path/to/start_script"
    stop program = "/path/to/stop_script"
    if mem usage > 95% for 11 cycles then restart
```